# Why can I call the last method on a fixed-size array while this type doesn't implement that function?

Tags: arrays, rust

I have a fixed-size array I want to get the last element:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];
```

According to the [documentation page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) of the fixed-size array, there is no `last` method directly implemented for that type.

After a quick research, I have noticed the [slice type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) implements the `last` method. All I have to do now is to find a way to convert my array to a slice. I can do that using the `iter` method:

```
let last = array.iter().last();
```

But I also have noted that I can omit the call to `iter` and get the exactly same behavior:

```
let last = array.last();
```

Why is this possible? How can the fixed-size array type call a method it doesn't implement? I have taken a look to all the traits implemented for that type and none of them have a `last` method.

*While I was writing this question, I also noticed the `iter` function is not defined for the fixed-size array type. Is the documentation partial? Or am I bad at reading it?*

Comment: The concept you're missing is deref coercion, which allows references of types implementing `Deref` and `DerefMut` to coerce into the `&Deref::Target` type.

Comment: The above is wrong, arrays do not Deref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case for the `array`-types, which coerce into `slices` of the same type automatically. [The docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html) have (only) a small sentence about this:

> Arrays coerce to [slices (`[T]`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html), so a slice method may be called on an
> array.

I both cases the array is coerced into a `slice`, so you end up calling `.iter()` and `.last()` on an implicit `slice`, not on the `array`.